# Magento Edit Category Issue In Admin

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I'm using Magento CE ver. 1.9.1.0 for one of my store, everything is working fine and as expected but the catalog/category. I'm not able to edit/delete categories from Admin Panel.

The Console details are as follow:

URL being hit each time I click on category name:

```
BASE/index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/<scurity_key>/?q=index.php%2Fadmin%2Fcatalog_category%2Findex%2Fkey%2Fbdf7b2cc9b890b6cb7e687a31bc7c35c%2Fid/3/&isAjax=true
```

**Get Params:**

**isAjax** : true

**q** : index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/bdf7b2cc9b890b6cb7e687a31bc7c35c/id/3/

**POST Params**:

**active_tab_id** : category_info_tabs_group_4

**form_key** : FeUR7dFe2MutCtcB

This always bring a blank category form.

Comment: Maybe your catalog_url table is too big so it leads to a timeout or out of memory, Can you find anything related in the error logs?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. And that was because of `Nginx configuration.` 
You can find the following lines

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; 
  or
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

in your site's configuration (/etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite.com).

Change it to

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
}
location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
    rewrite / /index.php;
}
```

Use the guidelines from http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento